# Interpolation error in python program

Tags: python, scipy, interpolation

```
from cmath import phase
import math
import numpy
import numpy as np
from numpy import unwrap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy
from scipy import interpolate
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
import scipy.signal.signaltools as sigtool
```

I have a data set produced by the the following codes.

```
for i in xrange(10000):
    v = i/10000.0

    if v < 0.25:
        k=0.4*(math.sin(2*3.14*90*v))
        l1.append(k)
    elif 0.25 <= v < 0.5:
        k=0.8*(math.sin(2*3.14*90*v))
        l2.append(k)
    elif 0.5 <= v < 0.75:
        k=0.6*(math.sin(2*3.14*300*v))
        l3.append(k)
    elif 0.75 <= v < 1.0:
        k=0.9*(math.sin(2*3.14*300*v))
        l4.append(k)


comb= l1+l2+l3+l4

k=[]

for i in range(len(comb)):
    i1=i/10000.
    k.append(i1)
    f.write(str(i1)+" "+(str(comb[i])+"\n"))
```

I am finding the local maxima and local minima along with their corresponding positions with the following codes:

```
loc_mx=[]
loc_mn=[]
loc_mnt=[]
loc_mxt=[]
for i in range(len(comb)-2):
    if comb[i] < comb[i+1]:
        if comb[i+1] > comb[i+2]:
            loc_mx.append(comb[i+1])
            loc_mxt.append(i+3)
    if comb[i] > comb[i+1]:
        if comb[i+1] < comb[i+2]:
            loc_mn.append(comb[i+1])
            loc_mnt.append(i+3)
```

Interpolating the the data with the help of local maxima and local minima with following code

```
loc_mn.append(comb[len(comb)-1])
loc_mx.append(comb[len(comb)-1])
loc_mnt.append(k[len(comb)-1])
loc_mxt.append(k[len(comb)-1])
loc_mn.reverse
loc_mx.reverse
loc_mn.append(comb[0])
loc_mx.append(comb[0])
loc_mnt.append(k[0])
loc_mxt.append(k[0])
loc_mn.reverse
loc_mx.reverse


min_mnt=min(loc_mnt)
min_mxt=min(loc_mxt)
max_mnt=max(loc_mnt)
max_mxt=max(loc_mxt)


x1=loc_mxt
y1=loc_mx
f1=interpolate.interp1d(x1,y1,kind="cubic")

x2=loc_mnt
y2=loc_mn
f2=interpolate.interp1d(x2,y2,kind="cubic")
f1(k)
f2(k)
```

I am getting the following error.

```
  File "emd.py", line 150, in <module>
    int_dt.write(str(k[i])+" "+str(f1(k[i]))+" "+str(f2(k[i])))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/interpolate/polyint.py", line 54, in __call__
    y = self._evaluate(x)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/interpolate/interpolate.py", line 448, in _evaluate
    out_of_bounds = self._check_bounds(x_new)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/interpolate/interpolate.py", line 475, in _check_bounds
    raise ValueError("A value in x_new is below the interpolation "
ValueError: A value in x_new is below the interpolation range.
```

Would be grateful to get any help in this regard.

Comment: What is `k`? In the first block of code `k` is a scalar, but in the last block of code `k` is used like a list. The error is saying that `k[i]` is below the range of interpolation which means `f1` or `f2` is defined with an `x1` or `x2` whose values are all greater than `k[i]`. In other words, the interpolator can not extrapolate.

Comment: Thanks ubuntu... That was my mistake... i just edited the question

Comment: Please use more descriptive variable names in the future. It will help you out a lot to avoid mistakes like this.

Comment: @ubuntu x1 and x2 are some numbers chosen from the list k. and i want to interpolate the functions for the whole range k. what can be done to resolve the problem?

Comment: @Bob: The values in `k` range from 0 to 1 (roughly). The values in `x1` and `x2` range over values much greater than 1. It doesn't look like `x1` and `x2` are being chosen from the values in `k`

Comment: Did you mean to divide the values in `x1` and `x2` by 10000. as you do for `k`?

Comment: @IanAuld yes sure.. from the next i ll be more careful

Comment: @ubuntu ya i divided the values with 10000. but then also getting the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The interpolator can not extrapolate.

```
f1 = interpolate.interp1d(x1,y1,kind="cubic")
```

defines `f1` on the domain `[min(x1), max(x1)]`.

```
In [62]: [min(x1), max(x1)]
Out[62]: [30, 9982]
```

`f1` can not be evaluated outside this domain. Since

```
In [63]: [min(k), max(k)]
Out[63]: [0.0, 0.9999]
```

`f1(k[i])` raises

```
ValueError: A value in x_new is below the interpolation range.
```

A similar issue affects `f2(k[i])` since again the values in `k` lie outside `[min(x2), max(x2)]`.

Comment: @ubuntu if i add the max and min value corresponding k in x1 along with some value for the y1 can i resolve the problem ??

Comment: @Bob, yes, that would avoid the error. You might also want to use `loc_mxt.append((i+3)/10000.)` to scale the values in `loc_mxt` down to the range used by `k`... but you would still need to augment `x1` with `min(k)` and `max(k)` and add associated `y` values. But that may or may not be consistent with what you want the interpolator to be doing....

Comment: loc_mn.append(comb[len(comb)-1])
loc_mx.append(comb[len(comb)-1])
loc_mnt.append(k[len(comb)-1])
loc_mxt.append(k[len(comb)-1])
loc_mn.reverse
loc_mx.reverse
loc_mn.append(comb[0])
loc_mx.append(comb[0])
loc_mnt.append(k[0])
loc_mxt.append(k[0])
loc_mn.reverse
loc_mx.reverse

@ubuntu